# forward paragraph -- ignore carriage return in comment

Tags: navigation

I like to use the forward- and back-paragraph methods to jump around my source code.  I would like it to behave slightly differently though.  Consider the following comment block:

```
// comment line one.
//
// comment line two.
```

I'd like to jump over the entire comment block, and not land in-between line and and two -- in other words, I'd like it to consider a contiguous comment block as a single paragraph.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is skip forward over all of a set of contiguous comments then `M-: (forward-comment (buffer-size))` should do more or less what you request.

You can of course wrap that sexp to define a command:

```el
(defun my-fwd-comment ()
 (interactive)
 (forward-comment (buffer-size)))
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Motion via Parsing](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Motion-via-Parsing.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting info, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.   My use case is I'm using a fwd-pgph and back-pgph to navigate through code, and I get annoyed that I get hung up in a multi-paragraph comment... it's a fairly minor point, but if I could could use the same key combo to get fwd-paragaph in code and fwd-comment over comments, that would be slick.

Comment: You can do that by defining a command that calls one or the other, depending on whether it is looking at or is inside a comment. See, for instance, `syntax-ppss`, including `(nth 4 (syntax-ppss))`.